# Menu_Item_Root assigned to menu I wish to delete

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

I wish to delete a menu I no longer need anymore. However, when I do I cannot rebuild my menu structure -- it fails with an error.

What I learned is that in the Menu database, this menu is the first in the database with an **ID of 1**, a title of **Menu_Item_root**, and an alias of root.

When I delete the menu, it disappears from here and the failure happens. I went and manually added it in.

Is there any way to get rid of this menu, leave what I want? Rebuilding the menus within Joomla doesn't help.

Thanks,
Doug Schneider

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete menus from within database (using phpMyAdmin, etc...). Use only Menu Manager from Joomla back-end. You can not delete menu which contains menu item marked as `default` (Usually this menu has ID=1). You can assign other menu item as default (home page for your site) and delete former menu item (and its menu if needed).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I did not delete from within the database. Instead, I actually went in and added it back directly there to get it working. I deleted from within Joomla, actually, and when I did that, I got the error when trying to do a rebuild after just to see. Another menu is already defined as the default.

Comment: Modifying database directly could cause bigger troubles. What was the error when you had deleted menu using Joomla backend before making any changes in the database? Restoring your site is possible. But if you think it would be easier you can start new one from scratch.